# python pickle size limit

Tags: python, numpy, size, pickle

i want to pickle a large (1810392*255) numpy array. However when pickling i get an error:

```
[...]error: 'i' format requires -2147483648 <= number <= 2147483647
```

Code:

```
import numpy
import pickle
l=numpy.zeros((1810392,255))
f=open('file.pkl','wb')
pickle.dump(l,f,2)
```

Is there a size limit? Is there a workaround? If not necessary I do not want to use hdf5 or something not build into python.

I also tried `numpy.savez` and `numpy.savez_compressed`.
Code:

```
import numpy
l=numpy.zeros((1810392,255))
numpy.savez_compressed('file.npz',l)
```

Saving works but when i try to load the data I get an error.
Code:

```
import numpy
l=numpy.load('file.npz')
l['arr_0']
```

I need to use `numpy.savez` instead of `numpy.save` because I want to store additional data.

Comment: tested on 64 bit MacOS and 64 bit Linux

Comment: what error are you getting when trying numpy.load() ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ms3xhsaV

Comment: You can create an issue in numpy. They wrote `# XXX: we can probably chunk this to avoid the memory hit.` Or change it and contribute: https://github.com/numpy/numpy

Comment: I created an issue on [github](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/3473).

Comment: Workaround:
`import numpy`
`f=open('file.npy','wb')`
`l=numpy.zeros((1810392,255))`
`numpy.save(f,l)`
`[optional: numpy.save(f,...)]`
`f.close()`

open again with:
`import numpy`
`f=open('file.npy','rb')`
`l=numpy.load(f)`
`[optional: m=numpy.load(f)]`
`f.close()`

Answer (score 0):

I have got the similar problem. The maximum pickle file I get is 155Mb. If you're planning to add more data, I suggest you to use a database like sqlite3 or firebase.